# Retrieving the contents of the html body using Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Is there a grunt task that can grab the contents of the html body and put it in a separate file?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Grab this</h1>
        <h2>And this</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Grunt's Copy Part of File to select the body.

Documentation is here.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-copy-part-of-file

For example

```
grunt.initConfig({
    copy_part_of_file: {
        simple_replace_scripts: {
            options: {
                sourceFileStartPattern: '<body>',
                sourceFileEndPattern: '</body>',
                destinationFileStartPattern: '',
                destinationFileEndPattern: ''
            },
            files: {
                'test/fixtures/simple-destination.html': ['test/fixtures/simple-source.html']
            }
        }
    },
})
```